# React Form with input field for duration formatted in hours or minutes as a string

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am trying to create a React form using Hooks that has 2 input fields, both are strings: name of movie and duration. The duration input field needs to be formatted in minutes or hours eg. '143m' or '2h' and if is not then an error will display saying 'please specify in minutes or hours'

I am not sure where to even start with writing the conditional function for the duration and how to render it in my form. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function Movieform() {
  const [movies, handleChange] = useForm({name:'', rating: 0, duration: ''})

  const validateDuration(input){
   if(){

   }else{
     return 'Please specify the time in hours or minutes (e.g. 2.5h or 150m)'
   }
  }
  return (
    <section>
      <div className='card pa-30'>
        <form onSubmit={ e => e.preventDefault() }>
          <div className='layout-column mb-15'>
            <label htmlFor='name' className='mb-3'>Movie Name</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              //id='name'
              name="name"
              value={movies.name}
              placeholder='Enter Movie Name'
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
         
          <div className='layout-column mb-30'>
            <label htmlFor='duration' className='mb-3'>Duration</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              //id='duration'
              name='duration'
              value={movies.duration}
              placeholder='Enter duration in hours or minutes'
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          {/* Use this div when time format is invalid */}
          {/* <div
            className='alert error mb-30'
            data-testid='alert'
          >
            Please specify time in hours or minutes (e.g. 2.5h or 150m)
          </div>  */}
          <div className='layout-row justify-content-end'>
            <button
              type='submit'
              className='mx-0'
              data-testid='addButton'
            >
              Add Movie
            </button>
          </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Movieform
```

Comment: It seems like you can use some regex expression to do the validation of the format that are you looking for... are you trying do some research about that?

Comment: @AliBriceño yes, it was a problem I had in an interview and I still haven't been able to figure it out. Would like to understand for future

Comment: This was for a job interview? :v Oh my God. They let you research a little on this test? Or you must to solve it without any external research/help?